# Double click select entire camel case word?

Tags: pycharm

When using the PyCharm IDE, if I have a type name in my python code (like BadUserCredentials) is there a way to get a mouse double (left) click to select the whole name? A double click currently only selects "Bad", for example, while a triple click selects the whole line.

I've already enabled these settings:

- Editor>General>SmartKeys>Use "CamelHump" words
- Editor>General>Mouse>Honor "CamelHumps" words setting when selecting on double click

Double CTRL-W will work, but I'm used to using the mouse.

PyCharm Community 2018.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should have the following combination:

> Editor -> General -> Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click - ON
>
> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Use "CamelHumps" words - OFF

Having both turned off should have the same effect. Both tested on IntelliJ IDEA UE 2018, but should have the same effect on PyCham

Comment: Thank you. I completely misread what it meant to Honor CamelHumps words.

Comment: You are welcome. I know from myself that sometimes this sort of tiny misunderstandings are difficult to get right until somebody points out :)

Comment: Works on v.2021.1.2 both settings are in Editor > General > Smart Keys

Comment: Any idea how to make it honor kebab-case words on double-click? ps. `this-is-kebab-case`